# Unexpected layer name when reading NetCDF file using terra and raster R packages

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, terra, ncdf4

I need to read a NetCDF file in R using terra package. Here is a snapshot of the NetCDF

```
(NC <- nc_open("Test11.nc"))

File Test11.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float Var[x,y,lambert_azimuthal_equal_area]   (Contiguous storage)  
            units: UNITS
            _FillValue: -99999
            long_name: Map1 Description
            grid_mapping: lambert_azimuthal_equal_area

     3 dimensions:
        x  Size:390 
            units: m
            standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
            long_name: x coordinate of projection
        y  Size:404 
            units: m
            standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
            long_name: y coordinate of projection
        lambert_azimuthal_equal_area  Size:1 
            grid_mapping_name: lambert_azimuthal_equal_area
            false_easting: 4321000
            false_northing: 3210000
            latitude_of_projection_origin: 52
            longitude_of_projection_origin: 10
            long_name: CRS definition
            longitude_of_prime_meridian: 0
            semi_major_axis: 6378137
            inverse_flattening: 298.257222101
            spatial_ref: PROJCS["ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],UNIT["metre",1],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]
            crs_wkt: PROJCS["ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],UNIT["metre",1],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]
            GeoTransform: 2630000 10000 0 5420000 0 -10000
```

---

Reading the file using raster:

```
raster::raster("Test11.nc", var = "Var")
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 404, 390, 157560  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
extent     : 2630000, 6530000, 1380000, 5420000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : Test11.nc 
names      : Map1.Description 
z-value    : 1 
zvar       : Var
```

The name of the layer is the `long_name` attribute of the `Var` variable, not the variable name itself. Is it possible to directly force raster to assign the name of the layer to the variable of interest (i.e., without using `names(R) = "Var"`)?

```
names(raster::raster("Test11.nc", var = "Var"))
# "Map1.Description"
```

---

When reading it by terra the name of the layer is incorrect.

```
terra::rast("Test11.nc")
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 404, 390, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
extent      : 2630000, 6530000, 1380000, 5420000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe (EPSG:3035) 
source      : Test11.nc 
varname     : Var (Map1 Description) 
name        : Var_lambert_azimuthal_equal_area=1 
unit        :                              UNITS
```

```
> varnames(terra::rast("Test11.nc"))
[1] "Var"
> names(terra::rast("Test11.nc"))
[1] "Var_lambert_azimuthal_equal_area=1"
> longnames(terra::rast("Test11.nc"))
[1] "Map1 Description"
```

The name of the layer is the name of the variable concatenated with the CRS dimension `lambert_azimuthal_equal_area` followed by "=1".

Which attributes are read by default by terra and raster?
I tried explicitly assigning attributes like `varname` or name to the `Var` variable without affecting how terra reads layer name.
Any explanation or suggestions?

Comment: Any chance to make your examples above reproducible by uploading this dataset somewhere?

Comment: An example file can be downloaded via this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_pDU2WjnCswWqj4rboIG7-HwjKVqthA/view?usp=sharing)